# The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA) when connecting to remote computer

Tags: c#, wmi

I try to connect remote computer by using winforms c#.

**My Code:**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var connection = new ConnectionOptions();
    connection.Username = "xx";
    connection.Password = "xx";

    var scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\111.111.111.22:6000\\root\\CIMV2", connection);
    scope.Connect();   // Exception occurs here..
}
```

I get below Error in line **scope.Connect();**

**Error:**

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in
>   System.Management.dll
>
> Additional information: The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you telnet to this port? Does your firewall and remote machine firewall is also configured to commmunicate through TCP 3389?

Comment: I can connect from remove desktop connection.There is no any problem.

Comment: What does this have to do with WinForms?

Comment: Our customer wants to connect by hand terminal

Comment: I'm also having this problem: Windows Server 2008 R2, all firewalls off, process running as Administrator. A solution to this would be greatly appreciated if anybody has any insight.

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure you did not run this application as administrator.

Thanks to UAC you need to run your application as administrator to get this to work.

See [How do I force my .NET application to run as administrator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-my-net-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7) to read how to add a app.manifest to your application, forcing it to run as administrator.

Comment: Thanks for aswer.I tried to add app.manifest and changed but it displays not administrator.

Comment: @user3580199: Did you follow the advise in the answer I included?

Comment: I solved administrator problem.İt displays admin=true. But i still have same error :(

Comment: @user3580199: Do you have all firewalls turned off, etc?

Comment: I can connect from remove desktop connection.There is no any problem.

Comment: @user3580199: But that is a different protocol. Try to disable the firewalls and check again.

Comment: This worked for me.  I was getting the RPC Server is unavailable exception, then after running Visual Studio as administrator, the problem disappeared.